# Encapsulating a self referencing console application method

Tags: c#

If the method `iAmPrivate` is `Private` then how does the following execute it? If I try to run PrivateMethod's  myPrivateMethod it is encapsulated why doesn't the same apply to `iAmPrivate` ?

```
class PrivateMethod {
    private int myPrivateMethod() {
        return 1;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args) {

    Program myProgram = new Program();

    myProgram.iAmPrivate("private");
    myProgram.iAmPublic("public");

    PrivateMethod pm = new PrivateMethod();
    //Console.WriteLine("this won't run {0}", pm.myPrivateMethod);  //not possible          

    Console.WriteLine("press [enter] to exit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public void iAmPublic(string s) {
    Console.WriteLine("I am {0}", s);
}

private void iAmPrivate(string s) {
    Console.WriteLine("I am {0}", s);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Thanks for the help... Now I get it!]

Changing the class `PrivateMethod` to the following helped me understand what is going on:

```
class PrivateMethod {
    public int pretendMain() {
        PrivateMethod x = new PrivateMethod();
        return x.myPrivateMethod();
    }
    private int myPrivateMethod() {
        return 1;
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        Program myProgram = new Program();

        myProgram.iAmPrivate("private");
        myProgram.iAmPublic("public");

        PrivateMethod pm = new PrivateMethod();
        Console.WriteLine("this will now run {0}", pm.pretendMain()); //now possible !
        //Console.WriteLine("this won't run {0}", pm.myPrivateMethod);  //not possible          

        Console.WriteLine("press [enter] to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public void iAmPublic(string s) {
        Console.WriteLine("I am {0}", s);
    }
    private void iAmPrivate(string s) {
        Console.WriteLine("I am {0}", s);
    }
}
```

The fact that I was missing is that `myProgram.iAmPrivate("private");` was being run from within `Main` so of course it is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `Program.iAmPrivate` from within `Program.Main`. This is expected behavior in accordance with the documentation for `private` because both are methods of the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Cause in `C#` Main method is a static method of `Program` class. From within `Program` class, you can access its `private` methods, what you actually do. But you can not access `private` methods of *another* class.

Answer (score 0):

Because `iAmPrivate` is defined within the class `Program`. All private members are accessible from the type in which they are defined, but not outside of that type.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

A private function is, by definition, only accessible inside the class that defined it. As such, Program can access its private function(s), even in static functions.

The private function in the PrivateMethod class cannot be executed by Program as you're attempting to access a private function from outside the class.